# Is there a way through the Visual Studio IDE to move buttons between ToolStrips?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, toolstrip

I have multiple ToolStrips with buttons on my form. I'd like to move some buttons from one ToolStrip to another. However, the Visual Studio IDE is not allowing me to drag the buttons off of a ToolStrip. I could go and edit the designer file for the form, but I try to avoid that as much as possible. So is there some way to do this through the IDE?

Comment: Upgrade to WPF so you can use XAML and you will smile.

Comment: Yeah I've been meaning to try out WPF.

Comment: It'll blow your mind at first, especially if you're used to the Winforms designer way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  Click on the control, Ctrl+X to cut it to the clipboard.  Click on the 2nd toolstrip, Ctrl+V to paste it from the clipboard.

Comment: In the form designer code the button is added to the items collection of the toolstrip. I found the name of the button in the AddRange method and simply cut the name out and added it to the AddRange method of the toolbar I wanted it moved TO. While not as pretty as drag and drop it kept everything else intact. The solution mentioned above creates a new button and made it more inconvenient because everything would have to be renamed.